# AEM Granite.author undefined on submit component dialog event

Tags: adobe, aem

I have component dialog with one field that has to be validated by checking another field value and to do so, I created a clienlib which catch the event of the form submit and do the logic.

On hppy use case the form will be closed and anything is ok

On worst case scenarion I want to show another dialog with an error message.

What I did so far

*formValidator.js*

```
(function(document, $, ns) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).off("click", ".cq-dialog-submit");
    $(document).on("click", ".cq-dialog-submit", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this).closest("form.foundation-form");
        
        var field1 = form.find("[name='./field1']")[0].innerText;
        var field2 = form.find("[name='./field2']")[0].innerText;

        var errorMessage = "";

        if(someCondition){
           errorMessage = "Some error message";
        }

        if(errorMessage !== "") {
            // Here the ns (Granite.author) is undefined and I don't know why ???
            ns.ui.helpers.prompt({
                title: Granite.I18n.get("Invalid Input"),
                message: "Please Check Values",
                    actions: [{
                        id: "CANCEL",
                        text: "CANCEL",
                        className: "coral-Button"
                    }
                ],
                callback: function (actionId) {
                    if (actionId === "CANCEL") {
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
})(document, Granite.$, Granite.author);
```

*.content.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:ClientLibraryFolder"
          categories="some-category"
          dependencies="[granite.jquery]"/>
```

*__cq_dialog .content.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="SomeTitle"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
    extraClientlibs="[some-category]">
    <content>
    // dialog content
```

The issue is Granite.author is undefined and from this [documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/jsdoc/ui-touch/editor-core/Granite.author.ui.helpers.html) I see that there is a helper Granite.author.ui.helpers which allow to create such a popup
[image]